# Live video streaming in android not supporting sound

Tags: android

I am working on a live video streaming application that work with Wowza Media Server.I am supposed to stream the video from an RTSP link.I have worked it with video view.Video is being played well but there is no sound.Can anyone help me please?

Comment: what is your device OS version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this link [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) Android has provided requirements for RTSP. And also please check the audio codecs, are they supported by android.

If you think audio/video codecs are fine then post your code so that it can be review.

Comment: Hi Syed,I checked the supported media formats earlier itself.It's H.264,.mp4 one.and my device OS version is 4.0.Whenthe link is opened in VLC player through device browser,it supports sound also.

Comment: VLC probably will have codecs which are not present by default. H.264 is Video codecs (having ext .mp4) BUT what is audio codecs you are using

Comment: audio is .mp3.I am simply using a video view to play the stream using Uri.parse(link) method.Is it ok ?

Comment: If I am not wrong mp3 is supported by all devices, so, you should probably check your code. I think there may be something wrong with your code. or try any tutorial.

Comment: MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(VideoPlayerActivity .this);
              mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);
              String path="my_rtsp_link";
              Uri video = Uri.parse(path);
              videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
              videoView.setVideoURI(video);
          videoView.requestFocus();
          videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
          {
              public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
              {
                  videoView.start();
              }
          });

Comment: This is the code i am using for the same.Can you please tell me where I am going wrong? @ Syed